# runtime exception cant run app in emulator

Tags: android, eclipse

I can not run my app in emulator.

my androidManifest.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="ch.adiuvaris.enigma"android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/appName" >
    <activity   android:label="@string/appName" android:name=".EnigmaPuzzle" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="Enigma Settings android:name=".GamePrefs" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="Enigma Help" android:name=".GameHelp" >
    </activity>
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true">
    </supports-screens>
    </application>
    </manifest>'}
```

and I am getting following error in logcat

> 01-24 22:42:14.741: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1224): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 01-24 22:42:14.741: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1224): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.engime/com.example.engime.EnigmaPuzzle}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.engime.EnigmaPuzzle in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.engime-1.apk]
>
> 01-24 22:42:14.741: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1224):at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
>
> 01-24 22:42:14.741: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1224):at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
>
> 01-24 22:42:14.741: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1224):at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>
> 01-24 22:42:14.741: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1224):at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
>
> 01-24 22:42:14.741: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1224):at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> 01-24 22:42:14.741: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1224):at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>
> 01-24 22:42:14.741: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1224):at android.app.ActivityThread.main
>   (ActivityThread.java:3683)
>
> 01-24 22:42:14.741: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1224):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 01-24 22:42:14.741: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1224):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>
> 01-24 22:42:14.741: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1224):atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>
> 01-24 22:42:14.741: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1224):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>
> 01-24 22:42:14.741: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1224):at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 01-24 22:42:14.741: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1224): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.engime.EnigmaPuzzle in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.engime-1.apk]
>
> 01-24 22:42:14.741: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1224):at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
>
> 01-24 22:42:14.741: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1224):at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
>
> 01-24 22:42:14.741: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1224):at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>
> 01-24 22:42:14.741: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1224):at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
>
> 01-24 22:42:14.741: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1224):at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity

Comment: have you using Eclipse ?

Comment: Package name differs `ch.adiuvaris.enigma`

Comment: I correct package name but still find error

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eclipse, try cleaning the project. Your manifest haven't been refreshed and that is why it complains about a class not found in com.example.enigme